# How to use semantic grid in Foundation?

Tags: sass, response, zurb-foundation

I am having some trouble with the semantic grid mixin. I'm am sorry if I am missing something obvious, but I seek you help. I have the following code:

index.html

```
<header>
  <a id="logo" href="#">Logo Link</a>
  <div id="search">
      <span class="prefix">#</span>
      <input type="text">
  </div>
</header>
```

app.scss

```
header { @include outerRow();
  #logo { @include column(8); }
  #search { @include column(4); @include innerRow(collapse);
    span { @include column(3); }
    input { @include column(9); }
  }
}
```

This works correctly with the screen wide, but the prefix stretches to full width in narrow mode. I am a newbie in this adventure, but I believe it recalculates on it own for narrow screens, or do I have to a @media for this to work properly?

to new to post images so here are links:

Wide (correct) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/icK4h.jpg

Narrow (foofed) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVJhB.jpg

edit: Well the solution seems to be:

```
span { @include column(3); @include mobileColumn(1); }
input { @include column(9); @include mobileColumn(3); }
```

although I don't fully understand it. Still not sure whether calling for a new nested row in the column is acceptable, as below, but it seems to work:

```
#search { @include column(3); @include innerRow(collapse);
```

Comment: hey, I think it'll be great if you specify in your post title which version of Foundation are you using, it's very helpful for other people looking for Foundation issues...

Answer (score 0):

Foundation has a default breakpoint at 768px using media queries.

So, when viewing on the larger device it uses the column() mixin and then on smaller screen size it uses the mobileColumn() mixin.

Also, setting a div (in your case #search to be a column and an inner row is going to produce unexpected results. You should wrap your columns in a separate inner row container:

```
<header>
  <a id="logo" href="#">Logo Link</a>
  <div id="search">
      <div class="inner-row">
          <span class="prefix">#</span>
          <input type="text">
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

and

header { @include outerRow();
  #logo { @include column(8); }
  #search { @include column(4); 
    span { @include column(3); }
    input { @include column(9); }
  }
  .inner-row { @include innerRow(collapse); }
}

http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/media-queries.php